# The usage of "but" in non-shift sentence

Tags: word-usage

I have found a sentence:

> He returned several times to India briefly, but only returned permanently early in 1915.

I believe this sentence does not contain any shift. We can say that

*He returned several times to India briefly, and only returned permanently early in 1915.*

I do not which know one is correct and why.

Comment: First, you appear to believe that "shift" means something specific about a sentence, so that "non-shift" sentences can be distinguished. This is not correct. "Shift" is not a technical term, just a vague impression. Second, the difference in expectation is signalled by _but_ and determined by the context; it is **not** signalled by the sentence itself. Logically, there is no difference between _and_ and _but_. It is up to the listener to determine precisely which presupposition is being contrasted with which here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"But" is used here to contrast the permanence of his return in 1945 with the temporary nature of visits up til then. Grammatically it's fine.

You could use a version with "and", though to me, the "and only" in this sentence sounds a little odd. If you wanted to replace "but", I would either use:

- He returned several times to India briefly, **and** returned permanently early in 1915. OR
- He returned several times to India briefly, **only returning** permanently early in 1915.

Comment: Yes, OP's answer with 'and' would work where someone has suggested say "I know Heathcote first went to India in 1900: I thought he stayed there until 1918?" _ "No, he was in England most of that time. He returned . . ."